# Slide Up/Down SurfaceView in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-animation, surfaceview, android-constraintlayout

I use Constraint Layout as root with 3 subviews:

- Textview
- Button
- SurfaceView (View.Visibility = Gone)

I want when I click on Button, SurfaceView appear (View.Visibility = Visible) from:

> Y = - SurfaceView.height

to:

> Y = 0

And when I click a second time on the button, SurfaceView disappear (View.Visibility = Gone) from:

> Y = 0

to:

> Y = - SurfaceView.height

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Animation"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/display_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dsiplay"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />


    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/animation_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    boolean isVisible = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        findViewById(R.id.display_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                isVisible = !isVisible;

                if(isVisible){

                    /*
                    * Start Animation slide to down
                    * */

                    findViewById(R.id.animation_view).animate()
                            .translationY(0)
                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                                    super.onAnimationStart(animation);


                                    findViewById(R.id.animation_view).setY(-findViewById(R.id.animation_view).getHeight());

                                    findViewById(R.id.animation_view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                }

                            });

                }
                else {

                    /*
                    * Start Animation slide to up
                    * */


                    findViewById(R.id.animation_view).animate()
                            .translationY(-findViewById(R.id.animation_view).getHeight())
                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                                    super.onAnimationStart(animation);

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

                                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                                    findViewById(R.id.animation_view).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                }

                            });

                }

            }

        });



    }
}
```

When I click for the first time it doesn't work (slide down).

Comment: `tranlationY()` move the view up and down on the screen. If you want to animate its disappearance, you should look at `scaleX()` and `scaleY`.

Comment: No I just want to move the view up down, but the first time (down animation) it only appear so fast it doesn't animate to down I don't see any movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SurfaceView` doesn't have the correct initial conditions. These conditions correct themselves after going through an animation, so that is why subsequent animations work. Add the following to the `SurfaceView` XML:

```
android:translationY="-150dp"
```

You could also do this in code but you need to do it earlier than in the `onClick()` handler.

Answer (score 1):

If it can help some one.

ConstraintLayout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


   ...

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/animation_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:translationY="-150dp" />




</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    float translationY;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        translationY = findViewById(R.id.animation_view).getTranslationY();

        findViewById(R.id.display_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if(findViewById(R.id.animation_view).getVisibility() == View.GONE){

                    /*
                    * Start Animation slide to down
                    * */

                    findViewById(R.id.animation_view).animate()
                            .translationY(0)
                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                                    super.onAnimationStart(animation);

                                    findViewById(R.id.animation_view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                }

                            });

                }
                else  if(findViewById(R.id.animation_view).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){

                    /*
                    * Start Animation slide to up
                    * */


                    findViewById(R.id.animation_view).animate()
                            .translationY(translationY)
                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                                    super.onAnimationStart(animation);

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

                                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                                    findViewById(R.id.animation_view).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                }

                            });

                }

            }

        });



    }
}
```